# sonarqube docker container's setting is lost after stopping ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, jenkins, sonarqube

I am running Jenkins server on which sonarqube docker container is running but we stop this server once build is done hence the sonarqube container's setting is lost, is there any way for it.

Please suggest me the proper way to handle this scenario.

I am running Jenkins on Ubuntu ec2 instance

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817344/how-to-persist-configuration-analytics-across-container-invocations-in-sonarqu) SO question?