# Running Sonarqube with docker-compose using bind mount volumes

Tags: sonarqube, docker-compose

I’m trying to run Sonarqube in a Docker container on a Centos 7 server using docker-compose. Everything works as expected using named volumes as configured in this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled_plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled_plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

However, my */var/lib/docker/volumes* directory is not large enough to house the named volumes. So, I changed the docker-compose.yml file to use bind mount volumes as shown below.

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    volumes:
      - /data/sonarqube/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - /data/sonarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - /data/sonarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - /data/sonarqube/bundled_plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
      - /data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /data/postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  sonarnet:
    driver: bridge
```

However, after running *docker-compose up -d*, the app starts up but none of the bind mount volumes are written to. As a result, the Sonarqube plugins are not loaded and the sonar postgreSQL database is not initialized. I thought it may be a selinux issue, but I temporarily disabled it with no success. I’m unsure what to look at next.

Comment: Good recommendations below. However I ended up creating a new sizable logical volume on disk. I then moved all my docker named volumes from the _/var/lib/docker/volumes_ directory to a directory on the new logical volume. Finally I added a sym-link pointing _/var/lib/docker/volumes_ to the new directory holding all the docker volumes. I now have plenty of capacity for my named docker volumes and my Sonarqube docker-compose file works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I think my answer from ["How to persist configuration & analytics across container invocations in Sonarqube docker image"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53738998/2191231) would help you as well.

For good measure I have also pasted it in here:

---

.....

Notice this line [SONARQUBE_HOME](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/442f950dae232fca8e1e919e017270971cee46f6/4.5.6/Dockerfile#L5) in the Dockerfile for the `docker-sonarqube` image. We can control this environment variable.

When using `docker run`. Simply do:

`txt
docker run -d \
...
...
-e SONARQUBE_HOME=/sonarqube-data
-v /PERSISTENT_DISK/sonarqubeVolume:/sonarqube-data`

This will make Sonarqube create the conf, data and so forth folders and store data therein. As needed.

---

Or with `Kubernetes`. In your deployment YAML file. Do:

`txt
...
...
env:
- name: SONARQUBE_HOME
  value: /sonarqube-data
...
...
volumeMounts:
- name: app-volume
  mountPath: /sonarqube-data`

And the `name` in the `volumeMounts` property points to a volume in the `volumes` section of the Kubernetes deployment YAML file.
This again will make Sonarqube use the `/sonarqube-data` mountPath for creating extenions, conf and so forth folders, then save data therein.

And voila your Sonarqube data is thereby persisted.

I hope this will help others.

N.B. Notice that the YAML and Docker run examples are not exhaustive. They focus on the issue of persisting Sonarqube data.

---

Try it out BobC and let me know.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you in a single command I hope so.

Create a new docker-compose file named as `docker-compose.yaml`,

```
version: "3"
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:8.2-community
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarqubenet
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
      - sonarqube_temp:/opt/sonarqube/temp
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: sonarqube
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - sonarqubenet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: postgresql

networks:
  sonarqubenet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  sonarqube_temp:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Then, execute the command,

```
$ docker-compose up -d

$ docker container ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the container is running and, as you mentioned, Sonarqube starts-up. When it starts, is it showing that it's using the H2 in memory db? After running `docker-compose up -d`, use `docker logs -f <container_name>` to see what's happening on Sonarqube startup. 
To simplify viewing your logs with a known name, I suggest you also add a container name to your Sonarqube service. For example, `container_name: sonarqube`.

Also, while I know the plan is to deprecate the use of environment variables for the username, password and jdbc connection, I've had better luck in docker-compose using environment variables rather than the corresponding property value. For the connection string, try: `SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db/sonar` without specifying the default port for postgres.